# Android Studio кракозябры при переходе на java 1.8

Tags: android-studio, кодировка

Хочу использовать лямбды и стримы. 
В build.gradle добавил:

```
  jackOptions {
                enabled true
            }
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

После этого лямбды начинают работать, но кириллица, теперь, отображается не правильно.
Кодировка выставлена в UTF-8 как и ранее.
Я использую JackSon. От сервера мне возвращается строка на кириллице и я
не могу с ней работать. Да и вообще не удобно...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если System.out попробовать?

Comment: Я так понимаю stream'ы работают исключительно с данными и понятия не имею, как работают Log.{x}, возможно у них по умолчанию указана какая то кодировка

Comment: System.out даёт такой же результат: I/System.out: 123 РїРёС€Сѓ РІ СЃРёСЃС‚РµРј Р°СѓС‚

Answer (score 1):

Написал в поддержку Google. Они создали баг репорт. Ответ:

> Studio team has said this is likely an issue in Jack. Marking this as
>   a blocker for investigation.

Поставили багу наивысший приоритет, Blocker. O_o :)
Значит скоро пофиксят...